# Open ReadableStream from remote URL (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

How can I open a readable stream given a remote URI? I am using Node.js over Browserify.

I have tried `request(url).pipe()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I answered in the main question  right now :)

Comment: Cronopio, can you please elaborate what you did?